# Cython - using stdlib <random>

Tags: python, c++, random, cython

I'm trying to make the c++  library work with cython using the following code: a parent that generates a random number generator and children that use it to generate uniformly distributed random numbers.

```
[rnd.pyx]
cdef extern from "<random>" namespace "std":
   cdef cppclass mt19937:
      mt19937() except +
      mt19937(unsigned int) except +
   cdef cppclass uniform_real_distribution[T]:
      uniform_real_distribution()
      uniform_real_distribution(double, double)
      T operator()(mt19937)

cdef class Child:
   cdef mt19937 *rng
   cdef uniform_real_distribution[double] uniform
   def __cinit__(Child self):
      cdef unsigned int seed = 123154654
      self.rng = NULL
      self.uniform = uniform_real_distribution[double](0.,1.)
   cdef set_rng(Child self, mt19937 rng):
      self.rng = &rng
   def gen_uniform(self):
      return self.uniform(self.rng[0])

cdef class Parent:
   cdef mt19937 rng
   cdef public list children
   def __cinit__(Parent self):
      cdef unsigned int seed = 123154654
      self.rng = mt19937(seed)
      self.children = []
   cpdef make_child(Parent self):
      child = Child()
      child.set_rng(self.rng)
      self.children.append(child)

[rnd.pyxbuild]
import os
from distutils.extension import Extension
dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)
def make_ext(modname, pyxfilename):
    return Extension(
        name=modname,
        sources=[pyxfilename],
        extra_compile_args=["-std=c++11"],
        language="c++",
        include_dirs=[dirname]
    )

[test.py]
import pyximport
pyximport.install()

from rnd import Child, Parent

p = Parent()

for i in range(300):
   p.make_child()
for child in p.children:
   a = child.gen_uniform()
   print(a)
```

However, though the code compiles correctly, the output of the `gen_uniform` function is really not what I would expect: the `test.py` code generates first 0.941197317223, then 0.743410046664 for ever.

Moreover, though I don't manage to reproduce it, changing `Child.gen_uniform`, I once manage to get random numbers (much) greater that 1.0

Eventually in a more complex code where I pass the `rng` pointer from a class to another, I get normal numbers, zeros, greater-than-one numbers, then segmentation fault.

Could someone tell me where the problem comes from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code

```
cdef set_rng(Child self, mt19937 rng):
  self.rng = &rng
```

creates a temporary random number generator (`rng`) by copying the random number generator passed to it. It takes a pointer to the temporary, and then the temporary ceases to exist at the end of the function, rendering the pointer invalid.

What you probably mean to do is:

```
cdef set_rng(Child self, mt19937& rng):
  self.rng = &rng
```

(i.e. pass it by reference). This relies on the fact that `Parent` owns both the `Child`s, and the random number generator, which all the `Child`s hold a pointer to. Thus, they all have the same lifetime. If this isn't true then you're in trouble and need to rethink this scheme (maybe considering shared pointers?).

Comment: great, thank you! (this is so obvious, though, I guess my c++ really is rusty...)

Comment: ok, actually could you elaborate a bit on what could go wrong with the lifetime? it goes well on the example, but on my complete code, I have children an grandchildren, and iterating as ``for child in parent.children: for grandchild in child.children:`` gives a segfault at the very end of the loop while accessing them directly through ``parent.children[i].children[j]`` does not give segfault...

Comment: I can't immediately guess exactly where that's happening. The best explanation is: `Parent` and `Child` are Python classes, and their lifetime is controlled by the Python refcounting mechanism (so should be safe to use). The danger is that `Child` (and presumably `grandchild`) has a pointer to a random number generator that is part of parent, but because this is a C Pointer (not a Python reference) that doesn't keep parent alive. Thus if you no longer hold a Python reference to `parent`, but do still hold one to a `Child`, the `Child` could have an invalid pointer.